# Service for home items catalog

Tags: web-services, catalog

I want to make an inventory of items at home. Each item would have a few key-value fields (such as `type=book` or `purchase_date=12.02.2024`, some keys mandatory, other optional), and possibly one or more images. I want to be able to quickly filter through the fields and conveniently see the images.

Just a regular online spreadsheet **almost** does this, except:

- I don't see how to make image handling "user-friendly" (thumbnails in the list view, quick show/hide full image)
- Also people very far from IT would use this catalog; handling filters in a spreadsheet could be a bit too hard for them.

Size of the catalogue will be modest, order of hundreds of items. It needs to be multi-user, with history record of who added/deleted/edited what.

Is there a ready online service for this use case?

Alternatively, I might think about implementing this myself, but I don't want it to become a part-time project. Launching a full-scale web service with database, backend and frontend would be too big investment; ideas on how I can "cut the corners" are welcome. So far I was thinking about running the very light backend (pretty much just translating requests from the frontend into DB queries) in AWS Lambda, using AWS Aurora for the DB. I don't know what would be the simplest option for the frontend (not much besides showing a table with filters and possible image popups).

Fully self-made solution feels like too much "inventing the wheel" for a use case which looks typical to me, so I'm primarily searching for a ready-made service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Homebox**

I tried [Homebox online demo](https://homebox.fly.dev/) and liked it.

[image]

> Homebox is currently in early active development and is currently in
> beta stage.

Features

- Create and Manage Items by providing a name and a description
- Optional Details for Items
- Categorized Attachments (Images, Manuals, General)
- Arbitrary/Custom Fields
- CSV Import/Export for quickly creating and managing items
- QR Code Label Generator
- Organize Items by creating Labels and Locations and assigning them to items.
  *(use the Create+ button to add Items, labels and locations)*
- Multi-Tenant Support - All users are placed in a group and can only see items in their group. Invite family members to your group, or share an instance among friends. *(Don't know how it works and if it has a history.)*

[Description and documentation](https://hay-kot.github.io/homebox/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/hay-kot/homebox)

[Reddit r/selfhosted - Home Inventory Solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/112ae8r/homebox_v080_release_home_inventory_solution/)

[Licence : GNU Affero General Public License v3.0](https://github.com/hay-kot/homebox/blob/main/LICENSE)

Comment: Didn't know until now that I need exactly this piece of software :)

Comment: This might be the thing I'm looking for, excellent recommendation! I might need more "visual" frontend, with thumbnail views... and no one stops from contributing to this project :-)

Answer (score 1):

**[Baserow](https://baserow.io/)**

Open source no-code database

There is a [free plan and a paid plan](https://baserow.io/pricing), you can also [self-host with docker](https://baserow.io/docs/installation%2Finstall-with-docker).

You can generate and modify a gallery with a grid (spreadsheet) and an online form.

You can search in the gallery (1) with or without filter.
You can generate private links and passwords (2). Be careful not to put in anything that is too valuable in your home items catalog. There is no role-based permission in the free and self-hosted versions. There is one or more admin and members.

[image: Gallery]

[image: Grid]

[image: Form]

Comment: Excellent, this covers my main gap with simple online spreadsheet, poor images handling. This could be the second accepted answer!